# Header response X-Amzn-RequestId from AWS is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am implementing an API APIGW v2 AWS, and when consume this API the reponse header X-Amzn-RequestId is not present, the header is specified on ExposeHeadersConfiguration, however it is not present:

```
ExposeHeaders:
 - "X-Amzn-RequestId"
```

[Header Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Zz3.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.